# asp.net getting folder hierarchy from database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've been given a rather large sql database with many sub folders that eventually all lead to different data tables. I'm doing my binding in the behind code with sqldataAdapter and coding in VS. I was wondering if there was a way that I could retrieve a folder and all its children from the database as one object/set so I could bind it to a radMenu. If not how would I go about retrieving a folder and its sub hierarchy? I'm pretty new to sql and only know the basic SELECT *, UPDATE, DELETE commands.

Just for an example here's a simple hierarchy:

**DB->directory-> sub-dir-> table**

```
CountryDB->China
       England
       Russia
       America -> Arizona
                  Montana
                  Nevada           
                  California -> LATble, SanFranTbl, MontereyTbl
```

How could I retrieve the CountryDB and its hierarchy and bind it to a menu?

If it helps, here's some of the options I could use for data sources to bind with:

```
 For inherently hierarchical data sources, RadMenu will automatically creates the menu item hierarchy. Such data sources include

    XmlDataSource

    SiteMapDataSource 

For table-structured data sources, RadMenu uses the ID to ParentID relationship to establish a hierarchy. Such data sources include

    DataSet, DataTable, and DataView

    SqlDataSource

    AccessDataSource 

For object-based data sources, RadMenu uses the ID to ParentID relationship to establish a hierarchy. Such data sources include

    ObjectDataSource

    LinqDataSource

    Any class that implements the IEnumerable interface such as List, Array, ArrayList, etc.
```

Comment: what sql server are you using? also what is the table structure its a little unclear here

Comment: sql server 2008 R2. I'm using the radMenu class from a package called telerik. The nice thing about it is that it can be bound to a few different types of data sources. I'll add the info to my post

Comment: still need to know the table structure of the database you are trying to query as it is unclear

Comment: Yes. Please display the table stucture of the tables which has the Data.